# Website not displaying correctly on an iMac

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I've built a website for a friend, which has been tested on my MacBook Air, mobile devices, a 21" monitor and a 42" screen as well. Throughout each browser/device, it all seems to have looked alright.

However, I've since been told that there are a few issues with the site on an iMac, which is roughly the same size as my monitor. No matter which browser or monitor I use, I cannot replicate the problem - but I can see from the screenshots sent to me that certain images, slider buttons etc are not where they should be etc.

Is there any reason this might be happening specifically on an iMac? And how do you go about fixing a problem you cannot replicate?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS properties donot run in Safari browsers. Make sure you have not used those properties in your site.

Add screenshots of both interfaces in the comments. So I can further help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've got some screenshots here:

https://ibb.co/JySTndN
https://ibb.co/rwcDqSk

Seems like it's the footer being raised too high on the homepage, and the image slider  (https://magpie.work/photography.html) overlapping the right arrow for some reason. I've tried to replicate it in Safari, but still no luck unfortunately.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running the web application in Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes, works great in Chrome & Firefox. It actually works fine for me locally in Safari too, but not for the client sadly!

Comment: What you can do is to check all the css properties that are not supported by MAC. Search google to replace these properties by equivalent CSS supported on all browsers.